# How do I know if I'm iterating on the last item of the collection?

Tags: c#, vb.net, collections, foreach, iteration

I want to do something different on the last `KeyValuePair` of the `Dictionary` I'm iterating on.

```
For Each item In collection
    If ItsTheLastItem
        DoX()
    Else
        DoY()
    End If
Next
```

Is this possible?

**Re-Edit:** I'm not using a Dictionary's values, I'm actually using a List of `KeyValuePair`s. I've converted them and didn't notice later, dumb me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreach loop, determine which is the last iteration of the loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476174/foreach-loop-determine-which-is-the-last-iteration-of-the-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the collection to a list (like LINQ's ToList()) and iterate with a for(int i = 0)... loop.

Comment: It's a collection, but not a list, so it can't be indexed.

Comment: I did this without noticing before in the code's flow. However, now I can do it even with a `For Each`, which is semantically sweeter IMHO. In other words, Accepted.

Answer (score 8):

Unless you want to implement the `foreach` yourself, use a counter (C# code):

```
int count = collection.Count;
int counter = 0;

foreach(var item in collection)
{
  counter++;
  if(counter == count)
    DoX();
  else
    DoY();
}
```

Please note that this will only work with non-streamed `IEnumerable<T>`, also, depending on the implementation, `Count` would cause the collection to be walked twice.

Comment: That's what I'll do, I think. I was hoping every collection to have an index - isn't it internally an array?

Comment: @Camilo - The Indexer is provided by the IList interface which inherits from ICollection - some collections implement the later or IEnumerable, hence have no indexer

Comment: No, you can't make that assumption. For example, you can iterate over a `LinkedList`, but it doesn't have an array as internal data structure. Concering your comment on Jani's question - how do you get your collection? You say it's streamed, then this method wouldn't work out quite as well either, depending on the implementation of `Count` on the streamed collection.

Comment: Yeah, that's what a for loop is for.  Why use a counter in a foreach?

Comment: Because you can only use a `for` loop if you have an indexer at hand. If a collection only implements `IEnumerable`, you have no indexer.

Comment: Collections don't necessarily use an array internally -- semantically a Dictionary puts no importance on the index (ordering) of elements, similarly for Queue (for index), Hashset (index, ordering), etc. Even if these abstractions use an indexed implementation internally, you wouldn't expect them to expose the details of it.

Comment: This walks the collection twice. That could be expensive, and sometimes isn't possible (imagine a stream of random numbers).

Comment: There wasn't a detailed description of the collection. Also, your first statement isn't true either, an `IEnumerable` implementation might not have an indexer, but could hold a count of elements. Considering the question was very vague, I had to assume most of the information.

Comment: @Femaref: You are correct. I should have said "it _could_ walk the collection twice." The point remains, this won't work for all `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 8):

I would make your own extension method. This implementation here guarantees you only walk the collection once.

```
static class IEnumerableExtensions {
    public static void ForEachExceptTheLast<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Action<T> usualAction,
        Action<T> lastAction
    ) {
        var e = source.GetEnumerator();
        T penultimate;
        T last;
        if (e.MoveNext()) {
            last = e.Current;
            while(e.MoveNext()) {
                penultimate = last;
                last = e.Current;
                usualAction(penultimate);
            }
            lastAction(last);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
          .ForEachExceptTheLast(
              x => Console.WriteLine("Not last: " + x),
              x => Console.WriteLine("Last: " + x)
);
```

Output:

```
Not last: 1
Not last: 2
Not last: 3
Not last: 4
Last: 5
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not use:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
// add items

foreach (string text in list)
{
    if (text.Equals(list[list.Count - 1]))
    {
        // last item
    }
    else
    {
        // not last item
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine, why is it not just this easy and if it is, why isn't there a .IsLast method that returns a bool for List items

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this naturally with an `IEnumerable<T>` as you won't know whether there are any more elements until you try to get to the next one.

However, in my [MiscUtil library](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) I have something called `SmartEnumerable` which reads one item in advance, in order to provide the following properties:

- `IsFirst`
- `IsLast`
- `Index`
- `Value`

See [this page](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil/usage/smartenumerable.html) for usage instructions. For example:

```
For Each item In collection.ToSmartEnumerable()
    If item.IsFirst
        DoX()
    Else
        DoY()
    End If
Next
```

You'd need to use `item.Value` to get at the value of the current item.

One point about iterating over dictionaries though - they're not actually in any order. So while you can iterate and there *will* be a first entry and a last entry, you shouldn't assume that they'll be the first entry added and the last entry added respectively. That may not be a problem for your use case, but you ought to be aware of it.

Comment: Jon Skeet can make a generic utility library with a name like MiscUtil something to feel proud of.

Answer (score 2):

I just had an idea that doesn't use a counter.

```
For Each item In collection.GetRange(0, collection.Count - 1)
    DoY(item)
Next
DoX(collection.Last)
```

Edit: sorry this is for a List, I had converted it before and intellisense gave me List methods instead of Dictionary methods.

Comment: I used your idea to build a IP String from either 3 or 4 octets entered by the user. See my answer below for details

Answer (score 1):

```
        foreach (var item in collection.Reverse().Skip(1))
        {

        }
        // do here the stuff related to list.LastOrDefaut()
```

Another approach is to maintain the iteration index and when hit the `collection.Length-2` or `collection.Count()-2` then stop the loop and do whatever you want with last element.

But as @BrokenGlass said beware of side effects that it may has on your application.

And generally you must use Linq with special care.
For example every time you iterate on a linq to sql collection, you execute the query again, so it's much better to run it once *eagerly* by simply calling `.ToList()` and use that in memory collection as much as you want.

Comment: Even though it "looks nice" I wouldn't do that with large collections just to do something special on one element - this approach would require for the whole collection being buffered instead of streamed.

Comment: Looks good, but `Reverse()` is not a function (i.e., it doesn't return a `List`), hence this is invalid code.

Comment: @Camilo It's not necessarily a List, that was just a variable name, and I changed it to collection for more clarity. then you can test it and revoke your quick downvote if you did that.

Comment: @Jani I didn't downvote, I upvoted and un-upvoted because it just doesn't compile. I can't call `Skip()` on `Reverse()` because `Reverse()` is not a function that returns something I can call `Skip()` on, unfortunately.

Comment: So first sorry for that and then here is the signature of Skip and Reverse, "public static IEnumerable<TSource> Skip<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count);" , "public static IEnumerable<TSource> Reverse<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source);" they all accept an IEnumerable<> and return IEnumerable<>. probably sth goes wrong in your program.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right, I tried it on a List by mistake. Upvote recast.

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution to build an IP String from 4 octets based on @CamiloMartin answer above.

```
 String sIP;
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 List<String> lstOctets= new List<string>{ usrIP1.Text, usrIP2.Text, usrIP3.Text, usrIP4.Text };
 foreach (String Octet in lstOctets.GetRange(0,lstOctets.Count - 1))
 {
    sb.Append(string.Format("{0:d}.", Octet));
 }
 if (lstOctets.Count == 4)
    sb.Append(string.Format("{0:d}", lstOctets[lstOctets.Count - 1]));
 else
     sb.Append(string.Format("{0:d}.0", lstOctets[lstOctets.Count - 1]));
 sIP = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I'm glad my snippet was of help :) It's interesting to note that since upwards of one year and a half ago I moved to C#, and now even my own VB code looks alien to me.

Answer (score 0):

With an Dictionary you have multiple options

```
Dim dictionary as new Dictionary(of String, MyObject)
For Each item in dictionary
    // item is KeyValue pair
Next

For Each item in dictionary.Keys
    // item is String
Next

For Each item in dictionary.Keys
    // item is MyObject
Next
```

I would suggest you itterate over the ValueCollection and either use a counter or do a Equals comparison between the current and the last item (which will probably be slower but you save a counter variable ;)
Don't forget to add a check of an empty list.

```
For Each item in dictionary.Values

    If dictionary.Count > 0 AndAlso _
        item.Equals(dictionary.Values(dictionary.Count - 1)) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Last Item")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Some other Item")
    End If

Next
```