# Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'T'

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, c#-6.0, null-propagation-operator

Trying to make `Feature` generic and then suddenly compiler said

> **Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'T'**

Here is the code

```
public abstract class Feature<T>
{
    public T Value
    {
        get { return GetValue?.Invoke(); } // here is error
        set { SetValue?.Invoke(value); }
    }

    public Func<T> GetValue { get; set; }
    public Action<T> SetValue { get; set; }
}
```

It is possible to use this code instead

```
get
{
    if (GetValue != null)
        return GetValue();
    return default(T);
}
```

But I am wondering how to fix that nice C# 6.0 one-liner.

Comment: That's really interesting. I think it might be a bug. All of the answers which suggest using `where T : class` are missing the fact that you're checking if the `Func<T>` is null not a `T`, as your second block of code shows. If that works then the `GetValue?.Invoke()` syntax should work also.
You should be able to write: `return GetValue?.Invoke() ?? default(T)`

Comment: @kjbartel: I think it's due to `?.` returning `null` if the expression was `null`, and not `default(T)`.

Comment: Func<T> is nullable.

Comment: why there is no error for `Action<T>` while thats nullable too. the cause is something else. and i dont think its a bug. and my guess is because Action return type is void but Func returns T. @kjbartel

Comment: I think, problem is that compiler can not determine result type of `GetValue?.Invoke()`. If `T` is `class` or `Nullable<>`, than result type should be `T`, but if `T` is `struct`, than result type should be `T?`.

Comment: @PetSerAl That should be the same problem for any non-nullable type. For example an `int` such as from `List?.Count` which you can solve by using `??` such as `List?.Count ?? 0`.

Comment: @kjbartel Result type of `List?.Count` is `int?`. It is know at compile time, that type should be promoted to nullable. Result type of `GetValue?.Invoke()` is `T` or `T?`. It is not know at compile time, should type be promoted to nullable, or it nullable already.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since not everything can be `null`, you have to narrow down `T` to be something nullable (aka an `object`). Structs can't be null, and neither can enums.

Adding a `where` on `class` does fix the issue:

```
public abstract class Feature<T> where T : class
```

So why doesn't it just work?

`Invoke()` yields `T`. If `GetValue` is `null`, the `?` operator sets the return value of type `T` to `null`, which it can't. If `T` is `int` for example, it can't make it nullable (`int?`) since the actual type required (`T` = `int`) isn't.

If you change `T` to be `int` in your code, you will see the problem very clearly. The end result of what you ask is this:

```
get
{
    int? x = GetValue?.Invoke();
    return x.GetValueOrDefault(0);
}
```

This is not something the null-propagation operator will do for you. If you revert to the use of `default(T)` it does know exactly what to do and you avoid the 'problematic' null-propagation.

Comment: Adding `T:class` clause introduces another problem, shall I ask another question or is it an easy one? I have `public class FeatureBool: Feature<bool> { }` and it says now *"The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Feature<T>'"*. Not sure if there is a better choice than `class` (I can't use `object`) or should I do something with `FeatureBool` itself?

Comment: I would just accept that the C# compiler doesn't allow this and that you need your option #2 in order to make this work. Not everything has to be a one liner, right?

Comment: The actuall error is `Cannot lift conditional access expression type 'T' to nullable type`. The `.?` operator wraps the return type of child into `Nullable<>`. The compiler can handle `Nullable<void>` but not `Nullable<T>`. thats why there is no error for `Action<T>.Invoke`.

Comment: @Sinatr you can do it in another way, refer T to struct : `public abstract class Feature<T> where T : struct`. then mark all `T` types as null. `public Func<T?>` ,`public Action<T?>`,`public T? Value`.however in this way you can only work with value types.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary You should write that as an answer as this answer is not correct. Yes it solves the problem for classes but it doesn't work for value types which will work fine with the second getter version from the question.

Comment: @kjbartel this answer is correct. _Since not everything can be null,_ thats true and thats why `nullable<T>` is not valid. because only non-nullable things can be marked as `nullable`.

Comment: my mistake. `void` is considered nullable type (there is no nullable<void>) . the `.?` operator leaves the return type as `void` .

Comment: @kjbartel `Invoke()` yields `T`. If `GetValue` is `null`, the `?` operator sets the return value of type `T` to `null`, which it can't.

Comment: ahhh.......  @PatrickHofman you're right. It looks at the type of the return value of the last method in the chain.

Comment: "This is not something the null-propagation operator will do for you. If you revert to the use of default(T) it does know exactly what to do and you avoid the 'problematic' null-propagation." 
`GetValue?.Invoke() ?? default(T)` also doesn't work. What are you trying to say with this last sentence?

Comment: I just ran into this error, and it may not be a bug in the compiler but the error message is very mislead and makes it seem to be a bug.  In my case I am applying the `?.` operator to an object instance like so: `obj?.Get<T>() ?? default(T)`.  This is inside a generic function and it will compile with *either* `where  T: struct` *or* `where T: class`, but not neither.  This is pretty strange since it's the same code in both cases, I guess if you need to cover both cases you just have to create 2 identical overloads with different conditions?.

Answer (score 8):

`T` must be a reference type or a nullable type

```
public abstract class Feature<T> where T : class
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know the `?.` operator is hardcoded to work with `null`, that is, it works for reference types or nullable value types, but not *normal* value types. The problem is likely that the operator returns `null` if the expression was `null` instead of `default(T)`.

You might be able to fix it by restricting `T` to `class` here.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: `Nullable<T>` is treated by the compiler as nullable, like it should, but [it's a value type](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e).

Comment: should have checked the reference source first !