# Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0

This is a question about C#'s newly introduced null-checking operator.

Assuming I have an interface like:

```
interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message);
}
```

and a function that expects a logging action:

```
void DoWork(Action<string> logAction)
{
    // Do work and use @logAction
}
```

Why do I get the following compiler error if I try to write:

```
void Main(string[] args)
{
    ILogger logger = GetLogger(); // Assume GetLogger() may return null

    //
    // Compiler error: 
    // Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'
    //
    DoWork(logger?.Log);   
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580536/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operand-of-type-t

Comment: Can you show `GetLogger()` please? Your `DoWork()` seems irrelevant to the problem you're facing.

Comment: Which behavior do you expect when `logger` is null? Make `logAction` value null? Make `logAction` to ignore the passed string (effectively, make it `s => { }`)? Don't call `DoWork(..)` at all?

Comment: @AndrewKhmylov I would expect logger?.Log to evaluate to either null or logger.Log.

Comment: @krillgar GetLogger() is irrelevant.

Comment: @DevinPrejean I see, but the other post is about using null-checking operator with generic types, which is fairly different.

Comment: @AhmedA.Hamid Ah, I see, then hvd answer is correct here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's nothing special going on with `?.` here, it works just like it does with `?:`: `logger?.Log` would give the same result as `logger == null ? null : logger.Log`, except for `logger` only being evaluated once.

The problem is that `logger == null ? null : logger.Log` is just as invalid in earlier versions of C#. `?:` requires one operand to be convertible to the type of the other, but neither `null` nor `logger.Log` have a type. You'd have to write that as e.g. `logger == null ? null : (Action<string>) logger.Log`.

Unfortunately, the introduction of that cast means there's no simple pretty C# 6 shortened version you can use, as the same applies to `?.`: `logger?.Log` is invalid because `logger.Log` does not have a type, so `logger?.Log` doesn't have a type either, but if it's an expression without a type, and it's not a method group, then there's nothing C# would let you do with it.

Comment: 1. Does this imply ?. is more or less efficient syntactic sugar for the ternary operator?

2. Do you have an idea why logger.Log does not have a type? It seems like the compiler has enough clues to tell what its type is.

Comment: @AhmedA.Hamid 1. The fact that makes it evaluate `logger` only once means to me that it wouldn't be fair to call it syntactic sugar, but I won't argue if you disagree. 2. Method groups never have a type. It can't be `Action<string>`: given `public delegate void MyStringAction(string s);`, a type `MyStringAction` would be an example of an equally acceptable delegate type. The C# compiler can't choose without looking at the context, but a language design decision has been made that C# shouldn't require looking for too much context.

Comment: I do agree with you ?. isn't just syntactic sugar. It's just that your answer gave me the impression there was a conversion or connection of some sort between the null-checking operator and the ternary operator. Is there any?

Thanks again.

Comment: @AhmedA.Hamid Ah, no, sorry for the confusion, there isn't. I just translated it to `?:` to show that the underlying issue already existed, that it isn't new to the `?.` operator, but I see how you can interpret my answer differently. Reworded to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change your interface to

```
interface ILogger
{
    //void Log(string message);
    Action<string> Log {get; }
}
```

Then you could use the `logger?.Log` notation.

The ILogger implementation would then look something like

```
class Logger : ILogger
{
    Action<string> Log => str => { /* Do stuff with str */ };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding to @hvd  statement

We can also use **Null Conditional Operator ( ?. )** with **Null-Coalescing Operator ( ?? )**
 If you write following code

```
string userName = null;
int len = userName.Length;
```

then

```
userName.Length
```

will throw the exception: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ConsoleApplication...
 Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

if you use the following code

```
string userName = null;
int? len = userName.Length;
```

still you will get the same exception

But

```
int? len = userName?.Length;
```

It will return null and will not throw the exception

But we are still having an issue. The issue is I am using int? (Nullable int) which is not good because people will prefer that if string is null then it should return 0.

**So we can do this by combination of null Conditional Operator(?.) and null-coalescing Operator(??)**

```
int len = userName?.Length ?? 0;
```

**Added**

we have another usage of null conditional operator too.

like when you are working with event handling in that case we can use

myCustomEventHandler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

where "myCustomEventHandler" is public event before C#6.0 we have to create local copy of "myCustomEventHandler" otherwise it may throw exception in case of muti-threaded application. whereas in C# 6 we can directly call the "myCustomEventHandler" without creating local copy and it is thread safe.

e.g. in C# 5

```
var handler= this.myCustomEventHandler;
if (handler!= null)
    handler(…)
```

in C# 6

```
myCustomEventHandler?.Invoke(e)
```

Comment: I'm not really sure about this statement: "because people will prefer that if string is null then it should return 0". This isn't how nullables work; there's so such thing as default values with null-checking operator, you either get null or value.

Comment: @AhmedA.Hamid, I have provided an example that it can be used in this way also. 

we have another usage of null conditional operator too. like when you are working with event handling in that case we can use

myCustomEventHandler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
where "myCustomEventHandler" is public event

before C#6.0 we have to create local copy of "myCustomEventHandler" otherwise it may throw exception in case of muti-threaded application.
whereas in C# 6 we can directly call the "myCustomEventHandler" without creating local copy and it is thread safe.