# Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'T' (2)

Tags: c#

I came across a weird behavior of C# compiler (VS 2015).
In the code bellow, compiler is happy with Value2, but complains about Value1: Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'T'

Why?

```
public interface IValueProvider<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

class Validator<T>
{
    public Validator(IValueProvider<T> provider)
    {
        _valueProvider = provider;
    }

    public T Value1 => _valueProvider?.Value ?? default(T);

    public T Value2 => _valueProvider != null ? _valueProvider.Value : default(T);

    private readonly IValueProvider<T> _valueProvider;
}
```

Comment: It's not strange.  `?` has no meaning for non-nullable types, ie structs. Without a type constraint, the compiler doesn't know whether T is a struct or not. `Value2` doesn't use this operator anywhere, which is why it works.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: But `_valueProvider` isn't of type `T`, it's of type `IValueProvider<T>`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - the `?.` is applied to the `IValueProvider`, not to `T`

Comment: This looks very odd to me. Looking into it now...

Comment: @HenkHolterman the error message is about T though

Comment: If T is a class then then the type of the expression `_valueProvider?.Value` is T. If T is a non-nullable struct it's `T?`. What should be the type of that expression?

Comment: There's too much happening in one line and too much code anyway, and you didn't show all compiler errors. Read [ask] and create a [mcve].

Comment: @HenkHolterman the error remains even if you remove `??`. It's not a mistyped compiler message. It *is* about `?.`

Comment: @HenkHolterman: It's not about the `??`. It also happens with `var value = provider?.Value;`.

Comment: @CodeCaster on the contrary, it's very clear and the snippet reproduces the problem. Just try this in LinqPad, you'll get the problem immediately.

Comment: The error makes sense if it refers to `.Value`, not `_valueProvider` as everyone assumed. It's `Value` whose type is `T`. The operator can't return a null for a non-null type

Comment: @Panagiotis compare the code in the question to the code in my answer. Also notice the "minimal" part in [mcve]. Less noise means less distractions for answerers and future visitors.

Comment: @CodeCaster this code was enough for others to reproduce and understand the error. The answer should make it clear that the compiler error is about the *Value*, since everyone assumed the error is about the provider

Comment: @Panagiotis I really don't know what point you're trying to make nor why you're being upvoted. The fact that someone (me included) was able to understand a question, can still mean the question contains too much irrelevant code. That a question allows for some fine mental gymnastics early in the morning doesn't mean that question could be written better, and I'm showing the OP some links where they can learn how to do that. Okay?

Comment: @CodeCaster: A *little* more than is actually required, but not very much, to be honest. Is it an *absolutely* minimal example? No. Is it close enough to avoid huge amounts of completely irrelevant code? Absolutely. Is it complete, allowing really easy reproduction of the problem? Yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'T'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580536/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operand-of-type-t)

Answer (score 19):

I believe the problem is that the compiler can't know the type of the expression `_valueProvider?.Value`.

Let's simplify this a bit:

```
public interface IValueProvider<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Foo<T>(IValueProvider<T> provider)
    {
        var mystery = provider?.Value;
    }
}
```

What should the compiler infer the type of `mystery` to be?

- If `T` is a reference type or a nullable value type, it would make sense for the expression (and therefore `mystery`) to be of type `T`.
- If `T` is a *non-nullable* value type, it would make sense for the expression (and therefore `mystery`)  to be of type `T?`.

As there are no constraints on `T`, there's no suitable type to be used, so there's a (slightly unfortunate) error message.

If the property were of type `string`, `int` or `int?`, all of those would be fine, and the expression would be of type `string`, `int?` and `int?` respectively. But there's no equivalent of that for `T`.

If you constrain `T` to be a reference type, it's fine, and the expression is of type `T`:

```
public static void Foo<T>(IValueProvider<T> provider) where T : class
{
    // Variable is of type T
    var mystery = provider?.Value;
}
```

If you constrain `T` to be a non-nullable value type  it's fine, and the expression is of type `T?` (aka `Nullable<T>`).

```
public static void Foo<T>(IValueProvider<T> provider) where T : struct
{
    // Variable is of type Nullable<T>
    var mystery = provider?.Value;
}
```

But without either constraint, there's no valid translation.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
public interface IValueProvider<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class Validator<T>
{
    public Validator(IValueProvider<T> provider)
    {
        var providerValue = provider?.Value;
    }
}
```

Shows this error at `provider?.Value`:

> Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'T'

And ReSharper gives this hint:

> Can't lift conditional access expression type `T` to nullable type

Because the type of `provider.Value` is `T`, which isn't constrained, so you could pass a non-nullable type for `T`.

Say you'd use it with `var validator = new Validator<int>(null);`, then this'd happen:

```
var providerValue = provider?.Value;
```

i.e.

```
int providerValue = null;
```

Which isn't allowed, as `int` isn't nullable.

The rest of the errors trickles down from there. So constrain `T` to be a nullable type, so for example `where T : class`, and it'll work.

Comment: In simpler terms, the error refers to `.Value`, not to `provider`.

Comment: Where do you see that "Can't lift ..." message?

Comment: @Henk VS2017 with ReSharper.