# Operator '?' cannot be applied during initialization

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors

I have to methods `Apply` and `Do` that I use to transform or evaluate expressions. In the following example they are used in a generic context and the generic type can be either value or reference. The compiler allows some usages while others are treated as errors. The code is similar for the failing and non-failing examples, except that the failing examples are variable initialization.

```
    public static U Apply<T, U>(this T subject, Func<T, U> f) => f(subject);

    public static void Do<T>(this T subject, Action<T> action) => action(subject);

    public static void SomeMethodA<A>(A a = default(A))
    {
        // OK: apply some operation to 'a'.
        a?.Apply(_ => default(A));

        // OK: apply some operation to 'a' and 'Do' assign result to 'b'.
        A b = default(A);
        a?.Apply(x => x).Do(x => b = x);
        a?.Apply(x => x)?.Do(x => b = x);

        // Bad: apply some operation to 'a' and initialize 'c' and 'd' with result.
        A c = a?.Apply(x => x);  // Error CS0023  Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'A'
        var d = a?.Apply(x => x);  // Error CS0023  Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'A'
    }
```

Why does the initialization code not compile when the non-initialization code does, and how is the error code (CS0023) related?

Comment: What's a problem to write like this: `A c = default(A); c = a?.Apply(x => x);`?

Comment: @SeM: The second part `c = a?.Apply(x => x);` generates the same error as in the example. See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46111202/3717854) for clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is almost a duplicate of [Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'T'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32580536/3538012).

The basic issue is that `A` is not nullable. Or at least, not known to be nullable. For your assignment to work, the compiler would have to be able to generate `null` in the short-circuiting case, and assign it to the local variable. Which it can't. Hence the error.

So, why no error on the other usages of `a?.`? Because those expressions *are never assigned to anything*. Without an assignment, the short-circuit is fine because the compiler doesn't have to assume something that might not be true, nor does it have to do something that would be impossible.