# Foreach loop, determine which is the last iteration of the loop - DataRow

Tags: c#, foreach

Please take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476174/foreach-loop-determine-which-is-the-last-iteration-of-the-loop).
Now i have a foreach like this :

```
//DataRow last = dsRequests.Tables["Requests"].Rows.Last();

foreach (DataRow drRequests in dsRequests.Tables["Requests"].Rows)
{
}
```

I want to determine the last iteration of the foreach loop.
So i tried this :

```
DataRow last = dsRequests.Tables["Requests"].Rows.Last();
```

But I have this error:

> Error CS1061  'DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'Last' and no extension method 'Last' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'DataRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write

```
 DataRow last = dsRequests.Tables["Requests"].AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();
 if(last != null)
     .....
```

forcing the *DataTable* to be enumerable then you can use *LastOrDefault()*. Notice that I am using *LastOrDefault* because, if the table is empty, *Last()* will get you an exception.

Another approach is through the old fashioned index over the *Rows* collection

```
    DataRow last = null;
    int idx = dsRequests.Tables["Requests"].Rows.Count;
    if(idx > 0) last = dsRequests.Tables["Requests"].Rows[idx -1];
    if(last != null)
        ....
```

In this example you have to test the number of rows after getting the count.

I should also add that the last example using the index to access the last row is more performant. However my tests show that on a 100000 loop the difference is simply 40 millisecs. Nothing to worry about.